# Google API key not valid for Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This question has been asked before and I read the solutions and none of them seem to work. I always get an error message that states -

"Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site"

I'm sticking to the code provided on the "Getting Started" tutorial, word for word. I've obtained the API key as they suggested and have even activated the Google Maps API V3 service. I still seem to be getting that error.

I doubt it's my code because I have literally copied and pasted the code they have provided (except have added my own API key in place), like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={My_Key_Instead}">
</script>
```

The link to the tutorial and the code I'm using is provided below.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Edit - I would like to mention that I've allowed any referer.

The solutions I have tried mentioned in other posts are:

1 - Getting a new API key

2 - Allowing any referer - (Part of the API access settings in the Google APIs Console) These are websites I accept requests from.

3 - Ensuring that Google Maps API V3 service has been activated.

4 - Ensured that it is a key for browser apps.

Comment: How have you allowed any referer?  What kind of key is it? When you say you have "read the solutions and none of them seem to work", what have you tried?

Comment: The solutions I have tried are:
1 - Getting a new API key
2 - Allowing any referer - Part of the API access settings in the Google APIs Console
3 - Ensuring that Google Maps API V3 service has been activated.
4 - Ensured that it is a key for browser apps. (This also answers your other question)

I have literally followed the tutorial step by step.